# Face Detector ML-KIT is not detecting faces

Tags: android, kotlin, face-detection, google-mlkit

I'm trying to implement the ML-KIT library together with CameraX to detect faces in a photo.
In this case, I'm putting a photo (in BitMap format) to be analyzed by a function that will detect the faces in that photo.

Initialize variables in **onCreate**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_photo)
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView")
    faceDetectorOptions = FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
        .setPerformanceMode(FaceDetectorOptions.PERFORMANCE_MODE_ACCURATE)
        .setContourMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CONTOUR_MODE_ALL)
        .build()
    faceDetector = FaceDetection.getClient(faceDetectorOptions)
}
```

Then I pass the BitMap to the function **detectFaces**

```
override fun onCaptureSuccess(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
                    val bitmap = imageProxy.image?.let { BitmapUtils().convertProxyImageInBitMap(it) }
                    bitmap?.let {
                        val photo = BitmapUtils().rotateBitmap(it, 90f)
                        detectFaces(photo, returnIntent)
                    }
                }
```

The function should analyze if there are faces in this photo

```
private fun detectFaces(image: Bitmap, intent: Intent){
    if (::faceDetectorOptions.isInitialized && ::faceDetector.isInitialized) {
        val inputImage = InputImage.fromBitmap(image, 0)
        val processImage = faceDetector.process(inputImage)
        processImage.addOnSuccessListener {
            if (it.size >= 1) {
                TODO()
            }
        }
        processImage.addOnFailureListener {
            it.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

But the **addOnSuccessListener callback always returns 0 the number of faces, even if a face has been photographed.**

Answer (score 0):

For same image you can try [MLKit Sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart) and check whether its camerax activity is able to detect the face out.

Some other things:

1. ML Kit support `android.media.Image` so you don't need to convert it to Bitmap
2. Double check whether 90 degree is the correct parameter, as ML Kit Face detector only able to detect upright face

Comment: `ML Kit support android.media.Image` can you  provide an example?